# Scrape data from the json response after logging in - BS4

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape phone numbers from the sample page. They are visible only to users after logging in.

So I created a system that logs me on the site. It looks like everything is working but I still can't display the phone number from the JSON reply link.

My system looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html as html_login
import json

url = 'https://website.pl/viewcount.php?contract=2062550&event=2'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#Remember logged in user
session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "https://website.pl/log_in"
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
tree = html_login.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='login[_csrf_token]']/@value")))
payload = {
    "login[login]": "my_user",
    "login[password]": "my_password",
    "login[_csrf_token]": authenticity_token
}

#log in action
result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data = payload,
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)

print(result.ok)

print(result.status_code)

print(soup)
```

My link code looks like this `{"count":63, "data": "50066677789"}` (nothing more, it is visible only to logged-in users). But my print result gives it:

```
True
200
```

Where have I made a mistake? Do I have to use any special tag to display this JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

status code 200 on login request suggests you are logged in 
after login you need to call get contact api not before.

also if the api returns json data there is method "json" `response.json()`
typically after login you get a token you need to send that token in further requests.
I will suggest you to open the website with developer console on and see how data is being exchanged to and from the server.